# Replacing a Cassandra node with replace_address flag returns "Cannot replace address with a node that is already bootstrapped"

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm using Cassandra 3.9 and the data on one of the nodes got corrupted, so had to wipe it entirely. I want to restart it and get all the data back from other nodes.

Using `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.replace_address=xx.xx.xx.xx` gives me the error
`Node already bootstrapped` since the IP address is the same. I'm confused on what are the necessary steps here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `replace_address` shouldn't be necessary.

Of course, it'll rejoin empty and try to serve requests.  Which will fail until a `nodetool rebuild` or `nodetool repair` completes.

If you want to re-bootstrap it, I would run a `nodetool removenode` from one of the "good" nodes.  Then restart Cassandra on the wiped node, and it should re-bootstrap itself while also not serving requests until done.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This might actually work! Can you also tell me if the node should be in the UN state on other nodes or not. I'm worried about this since I read somewhere that it should be DN on other nodes while it bootstraps, but it's UN for me here

Comment: @SomilShah While it's bootstrapping, it should appear as UJ (up/joining).  If it's UN, that means it's able to serve requests.

Comment: That's weird. I killed it as soon as it showed UN. I don't know what could be going wrong here. Please let me know if anything strikes. Else, thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @SomilShah so if it joined and immediately went to UN, that means bootstrapping didn't/won't happen.  Is the wiped node a seed node?  By default, if the node finds itself in its own seed list, it will not bootstrap.

Comment: It was a seed node, but I changed the config on the dead node, as well as removed it from other nodes and restarted the good ones

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this exception with `replace_address`:

```
Cannot replace address with a node that is already bootstrapped
```

because you didn't wipe out the `data/` directory completely.

A node is flagged as "bootstrapped" when the `bootstrapped` column in the `system.local` table is set to `COMPLETED`. If the `data/` directory is empty on startup, the `system.local` table will be empty so the node would bootstrap as normal. The exceptions are:

1. The node itself is listed in its `seeds` list in `cassandra.yaml`.
2. The `auto_bootstrap` property is set to `false` in `cassandra.yaml`.